# OctoberCMS Migrate Table

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am very new to octobercms and I have experience in  using laravel 4.2 .

I wanna ask how to create a table using artisan in cmd? Or is it in octobercms does not need to use cmd to create table? Any link with details tutorial to share?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are needing a table for a plugin, then [these docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/structure#migration-structure) will help you. Note that I am voting to close this question as it does not meet the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to create a plugin : `php artisan create:plugin MyCompagny.MyPlugin`

Then, you can create a model (table) : `php artisan create:model MyCompagny.MyPlugin Nameofthemodel`

Then you can edit the migration file to fit your need, and run `php artisan plugin:refresh MyCompagny.MyPlugin`

**Note that OctoberCMS is based on Laravel 5.0**

That's it! Hope its help

Comment: thank you , this is useful. but the model creation cmd is incorrect, should be: create:model

Answer (score 0):

Though the above answer is correct, another solution for creating tables would be using [Rainlab.Builder](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) plugin, which has its own user interface to easily create tables, Models, Controllers and many more )